# User authentication with React context

Tags: reactjs

I'm not sure why this isn't working. When the `login` function gets called, everything works except for the line `user = res.headers['access-token'];`. `user` remains undefined. My authentication system is based off this: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/authentication-in-react-applications

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const AuthContext = React.createContext();
const url = 'http://localhost:3001/auth/sign_in';

function AuthProvider(props) {
  let user;

  async function login(e, email, password) {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const res = await axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: url,
        data: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
      });
      localStorage.setItem('token', res.headers['access-token']);
      localStorage.setItem('client', res.headers['client']);
      localStorage.setItem('uid', res.headers['uid']);
      user = res.headers['access-token'];
      console.log('Logged in');
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{ user, login, logout, register }}
      {...props}
    />
  );
}

const useAuth = () => React.useContext(AuthContext);

export { AuthProvider, useAuth };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out all I needed to do was use `useState`.

```
function AuthProvider(props) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState();

  async function login(e, email, password) {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const res = await axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: url,
        data: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
      });
      localStorage.setItem('token', res.headers['access-token']);
      localStorage.setItem('client', res.headers['client']);
      localStorage.setItem('uid', res.headers['uid']);
      setUser(res.headers['access-token']);
      console.log('Logged in');
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{ user, login, logout, register }}
      {...props}
    />
  );
}
```